# iPhone Simulator - Strange memory leak when using Photo Library

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, photolibrary

I'm having a very strange memory leak when showing the Photo Library for picking a photo in my application. I get a 32.5 KB memory leaked triggered by MusicLibrary. It looks like this

Leaked Object   #   Address Size              Responsible Library   Responsible Frame
Malloc 32.50 KB,    0x7805c00   32.50 KB    MusicLibrary    MemNewPtrClear

It's very strange since I'm not using Music Library at all. Anyone any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Test it on the device first: the simulator *frequently* reports strange, odd, and just plain wrong memory leaks and allocations. Apple's documentation advises you not to use the simulator for memory testing unless absolutely required (there are a few scenarios where it's specifically needed for certain tools, but these are rare).

Comment: I will try that and post the results, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak doesn't appear anymore when testing on device. Thanks @lxt.